# Problema al pasar datos de input tipo file a un documento php

Tags: php, javascript, html

Resulta que estoy tratando de mandar un archivo a mi servidor, pero el problema es que cuando mando el formulario al documento de php, no me toma el valor. El codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```css
subir{
 padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #007ee5;
 border-radius: 4px;
    color:#fff;
    border:0px solid #fff;
 width: 95px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div id="principal">
 <form action="actions/informes.php" method="POST">
  <label for= "upload-file" class = "subir">Examinar...</label>
  <input type="file" id="upload-file" name="archivo" value="Cargar      actividad" style="display: none;" onchange="Cambiar()"/>
  <div id="info"></div> 
    <input type="submit" value= "Guardar informe" id="enivar"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

y este es el php que recibe el formulario:

```html
<?php
 require_once "conexion.php";
 $archivos = $_FILES['archivo'];
 
 echo $archivos;
 echo "</br>";
 var_dump($_FILES['archivo']);
 echo "</br>";
 
  if(!empty($archivo["name"])){
   if($archivo["type"] == "application/pdf"){
    if($archivo["size"] <= 2097152){
     $archivo_valido = true;
     move_uploaded_file($fichero['tmp_name'], "../upload/".$fichero["name"]);
    } else {
     $archivo_valido = false;
     $errores['archivo'] = "El archivo ". $fichero['name'] ." que intenta subir es muy pesado maximo 2mb";
    }
   } else {
    $archivo_valido = false;
    $errores['archivo'] = "El archivo ". $fichero['name'] ." que intenta subir no es extensión .pdf";
   }
  } else {
   $archivo_valido = false;
   $errores['archivo'] = "Por favor escoga el informe a subir antes de continuar";
  }
  
 var_dump ($errores);
 ?>
```

y este es el var_dump de $_POST:

array(2) { ["cursos"]=> string(1) "0" ["archivo"]=> string(43) "MI-LIBRITO-DE-LAS-VOCALES-PARA-RECORTAR.pdf" }

como pueden ver, pasa el dato del archivo pero no me esta asignando el valor, es mas hice un var_dump sobre $_FILES['archivo'] y me dice que es nulo

Esto mismo lo utilice en otro documento y funciona perfecto, y lo unico que hice fue copiar y pegar ya verifique y esta igual pero no funciona, no se que pueda ser, si alguien me puede ayudar lo agradeceria mucho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el elemento `form` te falta especificar el atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"` para poder subir archivos.

- `multipart/form-data` -> Este valor es obligatorio cuando utiliza formularios que tienen un control de carga de archivos.

Ejemplo:

```
<form action="actions/informes.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```